# Polygon with Mesh in ParametricPlot3D

Tags: plotting

```
b = 4; a = 1;
ParametricPlot3D[{ (b + a Cos[t]) Sin[v], (b + a Cos[t]) Cos[v], 
  a Sin[t]}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, {t, -Pi, Pi}, Mesh -> {18, 3}]
```

Wish to show a square section torus.Got such polygon section plots before, but unable to now. Because Version has (now 11) changed? Thanks.

To consider a 1D line analogue, how do we modify

```
ParametricPlot[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/3}, Mesh -> 5]
```

in order to get a hexagon? At present plots default to a smooth Mesh$ -> \infty$

In other words if we specify in order to make the number of steps in smooth circle 1D case from $\infty$ to a finite number coarse 6 mesh for a hexagon, perhaps we could in the smooth 2D torus case also reduce the double $\infty$ mesh to a coarse finite pair $(18,3)$ of prismatic surfaces. Required is a drastic reduction in number of steps to define the meridian of the torus.

A link about solid angles refers to its geometry as a [toroidal polyhedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_geometry)

Comment: You have two separate questions here, no? I recommend keeping this one as is, and possibly accepting kglr’s answer (or letting them know what is off with it), then creating a new question with your “EDIT1”.

Comment: Not really, I did not perhaps explain enough assuming it was clear, but seems is not clear enough.   Hope the added comment  explains what I mean. Else I would later add an image from structural s/w e.g., Blend. But I think Mathematica has the capability for such coarse mesh depiction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** Using a combination of options `MaxRecursion -> 0`, `Mesh -> Full` and `PlotPoints -> {p1, p2}`:

```
b = 4; a = 1;

ParametricPlot3D[{(b + a Cos[t]) Sin[v], (b + a Cos[t]) Cos[v], a Sin[t]}, 
 {v, 0, 2 Pi}, {t, -Pi, Pi},
 MaxRecursion -> 0, PlotPoints -> {19, 5}, Mesh -> Full, 
 PlotLabel -> Style[Row[{PlotPoints, " -> ", {19, 5}}], 16, Black], 
 PlotStyle -> Opacity[.2], Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Use the iterator `{t, -3 Pi/4, 5 Pi/4}` instead of `{t, -Pi, Pi}` to get

[image]

***Additional examples:***

```
ClearAll[pp3D]

pp3D = ParametricPlot3D[{(b + a Cos[t]) Sin[v], (b + a Cos[t]) Cos[v], a Sin[t]}, 
    {v, 0, 2 Pi}, {t, -Pi, Pi}, 
    MaxRecursion -> 0, Mesh -> Full, PlotPoints -> {#, #2}, 
    PlotLabel -> Style[Row[{PlotPoints, " -> ", {#, #2}}], 16, Black],
    PlotStyle -> Opacity[.2], ##3, 
    Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, ImageSize -> Medium] &;
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

Add the option `BoundaryStyle -> Black`:

```
b = 4; a = 1;
ParametricPlot3D[{(b + a Cos[t]) Sin[v], (b + a Cos[t]) Cos[v],  a Sin[t]}, 
  {v, 0, 2 Pi}, {t, -Pi, Pi}, Mesh -> {18, 3}, BoundaryStyle -> Black]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that is exacltly it !!